# array over array create folder ansible

Tags: ansible

I tried `with_items` with `*` but look like it doesn't support.

`vars/main.yml`

```
---
Z:
  A1:
    - "a"
    - "b"
  A2: "c"
  A3:
    - "d"
    - "e"
```

`tasks/main.yml`

```
---
- name: Create folder
  file:
    path: "{{ item }}"
    state: directory
    mode: '0755'
    owner: tomcat
    group: tomcat
  with_items:
    - "/opt/Z/{{ Z.A1.* }}"
    - "/opt/Z/{{ Z.A1.* }}/in"
    - "/opt/Z/{{ Z.A1.* }}/in/output/"
    - "/opt/Z/{{ Z.A1.* }}/in/output/fail"
    - "/opt/Z/{{ Z.A1.* }}/in/output/success"
```

I would like to get the following output, I'm not sure how to use `with_items` with array over array.

```
  /opt/Z/a
  /opt/Z/a/in
  /opt/Z/a/in/output/
  /opt/Z/a/in/output/fail
  /opt/Z/a/in/output/success

  /opt/Z/b
  /opt/Z/b/in
  /opt/Z/b/in/output/
  /opt/Z/b/in/output/fail
  /opt/Z/b/in/output/success
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The filter [product](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#product-filters) does the job. For example the play

```yaml
      vars:
        Z:
          A1:
            - "a"
            - "b"
          A2:
            - "c"
          A3:
            - "d"
            - "e"
        list2:
          - ""
          - "/in"
          - "/in/output/"
          - "/in/output/fail"
          - "/in/output/success"

      tasks:
        - debug:
            msg: "/opt/Z/{{ item.0 }}{{ item.1 }}"
          loop: "{{ Z.A1|product(list2)|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
      msg: /opt/Z/a
      msg: /opt/Z/a/in
      msg: /opt/Z/a/in/output/
      msg: /opt/Z/a/in/output/fail
      msg: /opt/Z/a/in/output/success
      msg: /opt/Z/b
      msg: /opt/Z/b/in
      msg: /opt/Z/b/in/output/
      msg: /opt/Z/b/in/output/fail
      msg: /opt/Z/b/in/output/success
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks good when using with `debug`, but when i use `loop` with `file` the output is bad :(

```
- name: Create folders
  file:
    path: "/opt/Z/{{ item.0 }}{{ item.1 }}"
    state: directory
    mode: '0755'
  loop:
    - "{{ Z.A1|product(list2)|list }}"
```

gives

```
# tree
.
└── Z
    └── ['a',\ '']['a',\ '
        └── in']
```

Comment: please do not add as a new answer. Please add as a comment to the answer, so they might get a notification as well.

Comment: It should be `loop: "{{ Z.A1|product(list2)|list }}"`. No need for the dash.

Comment: Thanks for you guys.